# Successive approximations for second order differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Ho can we obtain the (approximate) solution for, a $2$nd order differential equation, using *successive approximations*?

All the info I found so far explains how to do it for a 1st order equation. Can you point me to the general method for a $2$nd order case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Transform the second order equation $y''=f(x,y,y')$ in a first order system, introducing a new unknown $z=y'$:
$$\begin{align}
y'&=z\\
z'&=f(x,y,z)\\
y(x_0)&=y_0\\
z(x_0)&=z_0
\end{align}$$
The successive iterations are defined by
$$\begin{align}
y_{n+1}&=y_0+\int_{x_0}^xz_n(t)\,dt\\
z_{n+1}&=z_0+\int_{x_0}^xf(t,y_n(t),z_n(t))\,dt
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you. A minor detail: what does it mean to expand r to second order as r = r0 + ωr1 + ω²r2? Do I have to simply solve for the r0, r1 and r2 and then introduce them in that expression?